# How to open an old .exe file to view it's (text) contents?

Tags: windows, text, executable

Look at this page: http://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/sd/sd/filesgrad.asp
Newer files are text files but older ones executables. How should one open them or do anything with them?

Answer (score 1):

The exe files are self-extracting zip files.
You can open them with winrar, winzip, 7z, and others, such as command line unzip that you can get on most platforms.

```
$ unzip -t grad93.exe 
Archive:  grad93.exe
    testing: GRAD93.DBF               OK
No errors detected in compressed data of grad93.exe.
```